# Input[type="submit"] always grey on IOS

Tags: html, css

Why input (submit) looks like this on IOS only, and how do I solve it?

[image]

thanks in advance

HTML:

```
       <input class="btn" type="submit" 
             [disabled]=""
             value="ابدأ الان">
```

CSS:

```
    .btn {
        height: 4.2rem;
        width: 10.4rem;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 6px;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        margin-right: 1.3rem;
        outline: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: #032C51;
    }
```

Comment: Are you confused by the lack of background color?

Comment: yes, I think so

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

```
        background-color: #032C51 !important;
        color: #ffff !important;
```

Still don't Know why it happens only on IOS

Comment: If you open the css view inspector in your browser, you will see styles from another source that overlap with your current styles. `!important` is needed to override the priority of the CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

`<input class="btn" type="submit" [disabled]="" value="ابدأ الان">`
Why do you have `[disabled]` there? it should only be `disabled` *if* you want it to be disabled.